# How Do I Remove Display Objects in External Functions with Corona SDK Storyboard API?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am having a lot of trouble adding and removing items to the sceneGroup from listener functions and other functions which are outside of the standard `scene:createScene` and `scene:enterScene`.

Every so often I need to completely reset a lot of the objects on the screen and I have a function `contentReset()` at the top of the scene, after the first two typical lines of

```
local storyboard = require( "storyboard" )
local scene = storyboard.newScene()
```

In `contentReset()` I delete some objects created in scene:createScene and add new ones. But they refuse to work with `sceneGroup:Insert()`, even if I declare the object names at the top of the scene file, as Corona has done in the Storyboard samples...

In conclusion/summary:
I would like to see how to manage the creation and deletion of sceneGroup members outside of the initial create/enter scene functions.

Comment: Well, I rewrote the entire app to use Director 1.4 and everything works flawlessly. I'm still curious about this issue, as I would like to migrate to Ansca's official API for this function, but alas the current iteration is quite buggy.

Answer (score -1):

I am using the same API,when I want to exit the scene I use a exit scene function and in that scene I use:

```
storyboard.purgeScene("scene");
storyboard.removeAll()
```

It removes the display objects,I am not sure if that is what you are looking for.